# How to change/remap ros node name in launch file?

Tags: roslaunch, turtlebot, ros-hydro, roslauch, remapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I would like to rename a node from a launch file which includes other launch file.
Is it possible?? If yes then how is it done.

Here is a launch file I am using. The included launch file names the node as turtlebot_teleop_keyboard. I want to rename the node launched in the included launch file. The following launch file does not rename the node.

```
<launch>
     <include file="$(find turtlebot_teleop)/launch/keyboard_teleop.launch"/>
     <remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard" to="teleop"/>
</launch>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198873/how-to-change/remap-ros-node-name-in-launch-file?/) by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 172 on 2014-12-04

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the docs (http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap) remap affects all subsequent nodes.

Therefore you might want to try:

```
<launch>
   <remap from="turtlebot_teleop_keyboard" to="teleop"/>
   <include file="$(find turtlebot_teleop)/launch/keyboard_teleop.launch"/>
</launch>
```

**Update:**

I have tried it with a simple example and having the remap tag before the node tag is the correct way:

```
<launch>
    <remap from="chatter" to="foobar"/>
    <node pkg="rospy_tutorials" type="talker" name="talker"/>
</launch>
```

Are you sure your teleop node actually has that topic? It looks the launch file you are using might already perform some kind of remapping internally: https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/9ab88c750754aab1c5b26ad68a03f5e1041207fd/turtlebot_teleop/launch/keyboard_teleop.launch

**Update 2:** this only describes how to remap a topic. Remapping a node name is not possible using `roslaunch`. If you have control over the launch file you can use an argument to allow passing in a different name for the node name.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on 2014-12-05**:
It still does not work. I am using hydro on Ubuntu 12.04. The output of rosnode list is

```
/rosout
/turtlebot_teleop_keyboard
```

**Comment by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on 2014-12-15**:
I commented the remapping so file looks like:

```
<launch>
  <node pkg="turtlebot_teleop" type="turtlebot_teleop_key" name="turltebot_teleop_keyboard"/>
</launch>
```

I includeed this launch file and tried your answer and it does not rename the node. Does that mean I can't rename nodes?

**Comment by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on 2014-12-15**:
Just to clarify. I am trying to rename a node after launching not the topics.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2014-12-15**:
What do you mean when you say "rename a node after launching"?

**Comment by [arp](https://answers.ros.org/users/4543/arp/) on 2014-12-17**:
In the example where you remap the topic from chatter to foobar, the node is of type talker and it's name is "talker".  Can I change the node-name "talker" to "speaker"??